# Find word with at least partial match

Tags: java, regex

I've been working on an OCR app that finds specific information in a delivery note. However the issue is that the OCR sometimes doesn't recognize the characters perfectly, for example 'delivery' becomes 'deiivery'. Since I don't have a lot of experience with regex, I don't know whether there is a way for the regex to match partial patterns? For example I've got a pattern that looks for 'delivery' and then takes the numbers behind that.

```
(?i:delivery)[\s\.:-]*([\d]*)[\w]?
```

however in case the 'delivery' becomes 'deiivery' the regex fails. This happens with other words/tags as well. Is there some kind of regex token that allows me to match the text even if the input fits only partially? The regex is executed on a Java application. I've found out about

```
.hitEnd()
```

but AFAIK this only works for partial 'beginning' match ('aa' is recognized with 'aabb' regex), not a partial 'whole' match ('aba' won't be recognized with 'aaa' regex).

Comment: For delivery, there's `de[li]ivery`. But I'm guessing you want a general solution?

Comment: If there are consistent OCR errors, you can use a regex with a lot of or's. Otherwise I'd forgo the regex and consider something like levenshtein distance to figure out word similarities.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yeah I'd prefer general solution, as I have many regex expressions I'm looking for in the text and I never truly know where the OCR will fail, but replacing the most common ones (l, i) is a good start